# I don’t know what bike to get

Tags: bike-selection

I recently sold my bike as it was too small for me. That means I need a new bike. I have £400 to spend on a bike and it must be 27.5 inch wheels. Please give me some help on picking a bike

Comment: Sorry but we don't give product recommendations, as they're too specific to one person's needs (which, by the way, you didn't tell us, so how could we know?).

Comment: What do they call a "garage sale" in England?  Try a few.

Comment: Get a comfortable one - make sure you try it out before buying.

Answer (score 1):

From all given informations, I suggest you to buy the same model of bike you sold, just 2 sizes larger. Look for a used one. 400 pounds are enough, and you will probably learn one thing or two about bike maintenance.

Or was it a kid's bike and you are an adult?